# член предложения

Tags: члены-предложения

Здравствуйте! Можно к вам?? какой член предложения слово  "можно"?

Answer (score 4):

Составное глагольное сказуемое с пропуском инфинитива: Можно к вам войти? Можно к вам заглянуть? Лексическое значение перешло на на вспомогательную модальную часть

Answer (score 2):

1. ***Можно*** — безлично-предиктивное слово (также предикатив, слово категории состояния), в данном случае **модальный предикатив**, который употребляется с **примыкающим инфинитивом**.

Два значения: (1) **позволение** что-либо сделать и (2) **возможность** что-либо сделать.

2. ***Можно (мне) к вам?***

Например: Можно мне к вам **войти /присоединиться**? Это вопрос о **разрешении** действия (значение уточняется по ситуации).

Возможность выражена в таком варианте: *Можно к вам **пробраться** или нет?*

3. В данном случае **инфинитив** подразумевается, то есть ***можно*** — сказуемое, но неполное. Предложение безличное, ***к вам*** — дополнение.
4. Большой толковый словарь русского языка

**МОЖНО**, в функц. безл. сказ. с инф. 1. **О возможности** для осуществления **чего-л**.; есть условия для совершения какого-л. действия. Сегодня м. кататься на лыжах. М. пойти в лес. На солнце м. загорать. 2. **кому-чему и с инф**. Разрешается, позволительно. М. войти. М. выключить телевизор. Есть ещё желающие? - М. мне? К вам м.? - Пожалуйста, присаживайтесь.

Comment: **Комментарии были [перемещены в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/151979/discussion-on-answer-by-sharon--); пожалуйста, не продолжайте дискуссию здесь.** Прежде чем разместить комментарий ниже этого, пожалуйста, ознакомьтесь с [назначением комментариев](/help/privileges/comment). Комментарии, которые не запрашивают уточнения или не предлагают улучшения, скорее всего должны быть [ответами](/help/how-to-answer), размещены на [meta] или написаны в [chat]. Комментарии, продолжающие дискуссию, могут быть удалены.

Answer (score 1):

Можно - сказуемое в безличном предложении со значением разрешения, позволения (еще одним значением слова "можно" является возможность: сегодня можно кататься на лыжах).

Answer (score 0):

СЕЙЧАС ПРИДУМАЛИ НОВУЮ ЧАСТЬ РЕЧИ. Категории состояния - неизменяемые слова с общим значением состояния. выступающие в функции сказуемого безличного предложения. РАЗРЯД - оценка действия: можно, нельзя, нужно