Не подлежащно-сказуемостные предложения: Можно войти. Запрещено разговаривать
Эти предложения обсуждались на форуме, но вопросы о синтаксической роли слов можно и запрещено  остаются, хотя конкретные решения предлагались.
И тогда возникает вопрос: что об этих словах говорится в академической грамматике?
ПРИЛОЖЕНИЕ
Тема 1:  Синтаксический разбор предложения: На уроках запрещено/нельзя разговаривать
Тема 2. Можно войти: инфинитив входит в состав сказуемого или это дополнение?
Тема 3. Какой член предложения слово "можно"?
 МОЖНО, в функц. безл. сказ. с инф. 1. О возможности для осуществления 
 чего-л.; есть условия для совершения какого-л. действия. Сегодня м. 
 кататься на лыжах. М. пойти в лес. На солнце м. загорать. 2. кому-чему и 
 с инф. Разрешается, позволительно. М. войти. М. выключить телевизор. Есть 
 ещё желающие? - М. мне? К вам м.? - Пожалуйста, присаживайтесь. 


Элементы структурной грамматики в АГ-80
Н е п о д л е ж а щ н о - с к а з у е м о с т н ы е
п р е д л о ж е н и я
§ 2423. К двукомпонентным не подлежащно-сказуемостным предложениям относятся предложения, структурную основу которых образуют сочетания предикатива или наречия с инфинитивом или косвенным падежом имени.
Это — предложения следующих типов: 1) Можно ехать; Приказано наступать; 2) Видно следы — Не видно следы/следов; 3) Наготовлено запасов; 4) Много цветов; Масса гостей.
Грамматическая характеристика
§ 2424. В предложениях типа Можно ехать; Приказано наступать (схема Praed — Inf) позицию первого компонента занимают предикативы и фразеологизмы с модальными значениями возможности, целесообразности, волеизъявления, своевременности.
Примечание. Praed — категория состояния.

Предикативы: можно, нельзя, надо, нужно, необходимо, должно (книжн.), возможно, невозможно, немыслимо, пора, рано, (не) время, вольно (разг.), мало, (не)лишне, (не)охота (разг.), лень, (не) грех (разг.), некогда, невмочь (прост. и устар.), негоже (прост. и устар.), незачем, лучше, а также жалко, жаль;

причастные предикативы на -но, -то, такие как суждено, дано, заведено, положено, намечено, запланировано, велено, приказано, задумано, решено;


ВЫВОД
Два компонента таких предложений равноправны, то есть инфинитив свободен. Поэтому не стоит искать там составное глагольное сказуемое, а подобные предложения лучше не разбирать в школе совсем, чем додумывать их состав.  Или же надо комбинировать элементы классической и структурной грамматики.
Кстати, у Кустовой используется терминология из структурной грамматики, когда она говорит о минимальной структурной схеме: Слова категории состояния могут употребляться с примыкающим инфинитивом: интересно узнать; страшно вспомнить; надо спешить; необходимо разобраться. Другими словам, это предикатив + примыкающий инфинитив (схема как в АГ-80).
И говорит она не о сказуемом, а о главном члене односоставных предложений.

Это безличные сказуемо-подлежащные (или сказуемо-безподлежащные) предложения с опущенным глаголом "есть":
Можно было войти
Запрещено было разговаривать

Аналогично
Хорошо было войти
Хорошо было разговаривать

Или
Хорошо - войти
Хорошо - разговаривать


Можно войти. Запрещено разговаривать. В АГ-80 сказано, что это двухкомпонентные  не подлежащно-сказуемостные предложения,  то есть обозначена  минимальна структурная схема. В классической грамматике это односоставные безличные предложения. //  Разумеется,  парадигма всегда присутствует,  и любые предикативы имеют такую парадигму.  //  Но классической  грамматике выделяют сказуемое, и проблема в том, что инфинитив включают в СГС, а предикатив у них  — вспомогательная часть СГС.  У Кустовой инфинитив примыкает к предикативу, о сказуемом речи нет. А у вас какое сказуемое, чем является инфинитив?

В структурной грамматике интересно описание предложений: выделяется номинативная часть  и глагольная часть, имеющая парадигму (для обозначения времени и наклонения). Здесь номинативной частью является инфинитив.  // А вот, к примеру, однокомпонентное предложение: Холодно. В структурной схеме один компонент, к котором совмещены номинативная и глагольная часть.

"инфинитив включают в СГС, а предикатив вспомогательная часть СГС" - нет такого термина "вспомогательная часть СГС". Это может быть частью сложного глагольно-именного сказуемого, но не СГС

"Хорошо было разговаривать" - тут сложное сказуемое, СИС+СГС.  Инфинитив в него входит.  "Нельзя было разговаривать" - аналогично. "Нельзя разговаривать" - аналогично (или можно считать, что теперь уже просто СГС, вопрос терминологии ).

Ответ на комментарий
Это вы так считаете, а кто-то думает  по-другому. Этот синкретизм уже утомляет,  он формален и условен по сути, поэтому там допускаются разные решения. А структурная грамматика — новый уровень описания. Он обобщенный, разве вы этого  видите (два обязательных компонента, предикатив  + инфинитив, и это всё!).
Можно войти — это вообще мутное предложение с двумя значениями (возможность и разрешение). Вспомогательная часть — не мой термин (это у Кустовой),  но СГС по семантике туда ни разу не походит. Я могу войти — вот это СГС.
Вспомогательная часть СГС, кроме собственно предикативности (времени и наклонения),  выражает также различные фазовые и модальные значения.  Здесь модальность отнесена к производителю действия, а можно войти — безличное предложение, откуда там СГС?  Поэтому вам приходится считать инфинитив дополнением, а какое это дополнение!  Это минимальный структурный элемент предложения.
Но вот вам ответ нашего самого авторитетного участника (4 голоса, а будет еще больше) https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/419399/член-предложения/419411#419411  У совершенных людей нет никаких сомнений, для них все однозначно решено.
 Составное глагольное сказуемое с пропуском инфинитива: 
 Можно к вам войти? Можно к вам заглянуть? Лексическое 
 значение перешло на на вспомогательную модальную часть.


"Вспомогательная часть СГС это у Кустовой" - и что, Кустова говорит, что вспомогательная часть СГС не входит в СГС ?? Вы так и сказали. И что Кустова говорит, что предикатив может являться вспомогательной частью СГС??

Зачем вообще эти "можно" как-то отделять от обычных наречий типа "допустимо"? "Допустимо войти?" - тут все понятно.

У Кустовой в односоставных предложениях нет сказуемого вообще, она ближе к структурной грамматике. У нее главный член, выраженный предикативом + примыкающий инфинитив. //  Допустимо войти - это разрешение на вход, а есть еще возможность (дверь не заперта). Вот и разбирайтесь со своим СГС,  где здесь модальность для производителя действия.  Я ее вообще не вижу, ни в одном варианте.

"Возможно войти?" - обычное наречие. "Запрещено войти?" - обычное наречие. Зачем выдумывать какую-то модальность и производителей.

Вы уверены?  Эти предикативы очень неохотно становятся наречиями, если вообще становятся. Я тут для "трудно" никак не могла придумать значение наречия.  https://gramota.ru/poisk?query=можно&mode=slovari&dicts[]=71&dicts[]=42

предикатив = предикативное НАРЕЧИЕ

Предикативное наречие - это предикатив, а есть еще обстоятельственное наречие.  Можно - только предикатив.  МОЖНО, в функц. безл. сказ. с инф.
